# Warning: opendir(C:\xampp\htdocs/objects,C:\xampp\htdocs/objects): The system cannot find the file specified. (code: 2)

Tags: php, foreach, scandir

I know it seems like this question has been answered, but observe:

> Error = Warning: scandir(/_js,/_js): The system cannot find the file
>   specified. (code: 2) , etc.

Code:

```
define ("__SCRIPTS__" , "/_js");

$scripts = scandir(__SCRIPTS__);
        foreach($scripts as $collection){
            return "<script src=\"".$collection."\"></script>"."\n";
        }
```

How does the above code return a "doubling folder" the location? Is there another step I need to take to remove the second occurrence during the loop? I can get it to work by hard coding it but I want to delegate to the config.php file. So... What do you guys think?

Answer (score 0):

Use `_js`. The `/_js` form finds a folder in the root directory on your system.

In fact, the warning message seems to be buggy (it displays a second ghost parameter or something), but this is not the main problem.